# PHP if statement and ob_flush

Tags: php

If they are same do nothing, if they are different do the bottom and make them same. Whole script is in a loop but the loop is only doing else. Like it is not checking for conditions. What am I doing wrong?

```
for ($int = 0; $int < 10, $int+1){
        $array = $getarray();
    foreach ($array as $array){
        $var1 = $array->id;
        $var2 = null;

        if ($var1 == $var2){
            echo ('skip');
        }else{
            echo '<br>'.$var1.'<br>';
            ob_flush();
            $var2 = $var1;
        }
}
}
```

Initially var2 is null and var1 gets string value. So it performs else and var2 gets the var1 string. 
Next Loop if var1 has not changed, it will equal var2. So it does nothing and skips

Comment: what value contains $var1 and $var2 ?

Comment: What loop? There's no loop in your code.

Comment: strings. var_dump on both var shows values after each echo. also when var changes.

Comment: fault may be in value of $var1 and $var2. specify the $var1 and $var2 value so we can suggest you.

Comment: put your all code  @biligjames

Comment: @u_mulder ya. if is a condition statement and not a loop.

Comment: your code is working perfect or not it's depends  what you got in $var1 and $var2

Comment: edited to add more of the code

Comment: Won't that loop infinitely?  Also we need to see what `$getarray()` does.

Comment: infinite loop is my goal. it is alright. just it is not skipping when they are equal. it always performs else

Comment: you have lots of error in this code $var1==var2 is not correct. you should write $var1==$var2.

Comment: here getarray() is empty array. it does not contain any value

Comment: Your for statement is completely and utterly broken.  Try looking at the documentation on how to loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code does not work properly, as how many times your loop will execute, your $var2 will become null, so not a single time you will be reached at the point where your $var1 & $var2 values are same.
So instead please try the following code.

```
for ($int = 0; $int = 10; $int+1){
    $array = $getarray();
    $var2 = null;
    foreach ($array as $array){
        $var1 = $array->id;

        if ($var1 == var2){
            echo ('skip');
        }else{
            echo '<br>'.$var1.'<br>';
            ob_flush();
            $var2 = $var1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gives me exactly same result

Comment: What is your loop and your both variable values?

Comment: @biligjames please check the code now. Your $va1 & $var2 will never become same as you write $var2 in foreach loop, it will every time overwrite with the value of 'null'

Comment: aaah yes thats the problem. where should i declare $var2 so it doesn't get overwriten

Comment: @biligjames please check this answer. Here I have written the code as you want. Please do check it once. Thank you.

Comment: thank you. null overwriting was the problem. declared var2 outside all loops now i got what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the logic of these loops but this is how you should do it:

```
for ($int = 0; $int < 10, $int++) {
    /*
     * I suppose getarray() is a function.
     * If you have a variable $getarray containing the name of another function
     * then you should change getarray() to $getarray()
     */
    foreach (getarray() as $array) {
        if (is_null($array->id)) {
            echo ('skip');
        } else {
            echo "<br />{$array->id}<br />";
            ob_flush();
        }
    }
}
```